# QTableWidget with QPushbutton inside: button not disappearing

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I am using PyQt5 and i have a qtablewidget where i list the items from the database. Every item has an enter time and exit time but all the exit time is empty at first. I am using a logic like if exit time is empty show a button, but if not show the exit time. I can change the exit time with the button and i want the button to disappear after the change but button is not disappearing until i restart the program.

I have another button for editing the rows and i used it to understand the stuation and plug it to a function to change the exitTime to empty. if i click the edit exitTime changes to the empty and exit button comes back but i cant make the exit button go by clicking the exit

```
def loadData(self):
    databse.connection
    result = mcursor.fetchall()

    row=0
    self.ui.carList.setRowCount(len(result))

    for r in result:
        self.btn_sell = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Çıkış')
        self.btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.handleButtonClicked)
        self.btnEdit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Düzenle')
        self.btnEdit.clicked.connect(self.updateDialog)

        self.ui.carList.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[1]))
        self.ui.carList.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[2]))
        self.ui.carList.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[3]))
        self.ui.carList.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[5].strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d')))
        if r[6].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') == "1000-01-01 00:00:00":
            self.ui.carList.setCellWidget(row, 4, self.btn_sell)
        else:
            self.ui.carList.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[6].strftime('%H:%M:%S %Y-%m-%d')))

        self.ui.carList.setCellWidget(row, 5, self.btnEdit)

        row += 1
```

[image: image of the list]

minimal reproducible example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMainWindow, QStyleFactory, QTabWidget, QInputDialog
from stack import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import os
from datetime import datetime



 def dbFunc(): # for creating the list for the first time
        db = [["ahmet", "yıldırım", "KS67AEA", "23:09:39 2021-04-09", "23:09:39 2021-04-09"],
                  ["mahmut", "celik", "TR67AKH", "23:09:39 2021-04-09", "1000-01-01 00:00:00"],
                  ["mehmet", "gezen", "YU67OKY", "23:09:39 2021-04-09", "23:09:39 2021-04-09"],
                  ["hakan", "duz", "PT67LDK", "23:09:39 2021-04-09", "1000-01-01 00:00:00"],
                  ["ayse", "kavruk", "EO67KHL", "23:09:39 2021-04-09", "1000-01-01 00:00:00"]]
        #print(db)

    f = open("dbText.txt", "a")
    for item in db:
        for i in item:
            f.write(i)
            f.write(",")
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()



   def toList():#read list
        f = open("dbText.txt", "r")
        dbList = f.read()
        dbList = dbList.split("\n")
        list = []
        for i in dbList:
            list.append(i.split(",")[:-1])
        list.pop(-1)
        f.close()
        return list
    
    def refreshFile(db):
        os.remove('./dbText.txt')
        f = open("dbText.txt", "a")
        for item in db:
            for i in item:
                f.write(i)
                f.write(",")
            f.write("\n")
        f.close()
    
    
    class stapp(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(stapp, self).__init__()
            self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.setupUi(self)
            self.loadData()
    
      

  #dbFunc() # for creating the list for the first time
dbList = toList()

def loadData(self):

    result = self.dbList
    row=0
    self.ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(result))

    for r in result:
        self.btn_sell = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Çıkış')
        self.btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        self.btnEdit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Düzenle')
        self.btnEdit.clicked.connect(self.updateDialog)

        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[0]))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[1]))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[2]))
        self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[3]))
        if r[4] == "1000-01-01 00:00:00":
            self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 4, self.btn_sell)
        else:
            self.ui.tableWidget.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(r[4]))

        self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 5, self.btnEdit)

        row += 1

def exit(self):
    button = QtWidgets.qApp.focusWidget()
    index = self.ui.tableWidget.indexAt(button.pos())
    if index.isValid():

        result = self.dbList
        now = datetime.now()
        time = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        result[index.row()][4] = time
        refreshFile(self.dbList)
        self.loadData()

def updateDialog(self):
    button = QtWidgets.qApp.focusWidget()
    index = self.ui.tableWidget.indexAt(button.pos())
    if index.isValid():

        result = self.dbList
        time = "1000-01-01 00:00:00"

        result[index.row()][4]=time
        self.loadData()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('GTK+'))
    win = stapp()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Uİ:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(424, 279)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 401, 221))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 424, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "surname"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "enterTime"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "exitTime"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "exit"))
    item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
    item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "edit"))
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit difficult to replicate your code, since it's based on a database of which we don't know the full structure (there could just be a problem in the mapping of rows/columns). But I'd say two things. 1. Reloading the table everytime is very inefficient, you should use a QTableView with a QSqlTableModel instead, which will make data management much more consistent and intuitive. 2. `focusWidget()` is not safe for this (for instance, your program will crash if using the space bar instead of the mouse to click), there are better alternatives but I can't list them here.